# Scratch cloud variables

Tags: variables, cloud, mit-scratch

I am using cloud variables in a scratch project. I haven't used the concept of encrypting and decrypting for cloud variables, simply checked if score is greater then high score then set score to highscore.

[image: Scratch forever loop]

But in the cloud data history, it is only giving the history of me. Others have played the game too and also scored high score. Their data is not shown.

[image: Cloud Variables]

Whats the issue with cloud variables?

Comment: Who are the users getting the high scores? Cloud variables cannot be modified by unregistered users or "New Scratchers". See: https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Cloud_Data

Comment: Please edit your question, supply a link to the project affected. I just tested your project "Car obstacle remix", cloud highscore appears to be working fine there. Please verify by looking at its cloud data history. You should be seeing two scratchers (Lead98Youlinger and heldlaw) setting new highscores today: https://scratch.mit.edu/cloudmonitor/418776322/

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this:

- Who played your game is all new scratchers or you are a new scratcher. (very doubtful)
- It could be because Scratch's cloud variables have many bugs.
- Scratch's cloud data doesn't show all data from who played the game. Maybe other players played before you played and it only shows nearest ones so it only shows your record.

And see this [cloud monitor](https://scratch.mit.edu/cloudmonitor/418776322), it seems to show the records correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to put the code toward the end of the game so the cloud monitor can list every player's high score. If you do that as you are playing the game, it will record every move so you only see your cloud history since it does not list every change if there are too many changes in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the game is setting the cloud variable, therefore you are setting the cloud variable to "their high score". To fix this you could probably just look at other games. Get some research and do other stuff like that. Like the commenter said, New scratchers cant set cloud variables. So this might be the other thing.

Comment: Are you suggesting column 'user' in cloud data history is the owner of the project rather than the person playing the game? I doubt that very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that people who are playing your game are not signed in
Otherwise, I'm not sure